# Converting a hash to Base64 encoding: Should I be storing the hash as a String or Byte before encoding?

Tags: java, hash, base64, guava, apache-commons

Had an issue with generating a HMAC-SHA1 hash. I convert it to Base64 and send it to an external system, who verifies the result. However, they're producing a different Base64-encoded hash. As far as I can tell, they're using Java Mac (javax.crypto.mac) to generate the hash, whereas I am using the Google Guava Codec API.

I checked a couple of online hash generators (i.e. https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html) and they produced the same hash as me. I tried Apache Commons Codec API and it also produced the same results. Yet, this external system was producing a different Base64-encoded hash. Secret/key and message are exactly the same.

As it turns out, converting the hash to a String first, not a Byte, was the issue. I was converting the hash to a String first and then encoding with Base64. The external system was converting the hash to a Byte first and then encoding with Base64. The online generators that I found seem to convert the hash to a String first, like myself, which is why my hash matched with the online hash generators.

Is there a proper way to convert the hash? For good practice, should I be using asBytes(), toString() or something else?

Here's the code using Guava Codec API:

```
import com.google.common.hash.Hasher;
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;

import java.util.Base64;

public class HmacSha1TokenAuth {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String secret = "12345";
  String valueToDigest = "TestUser";

  byte[] key = secret.getBytes();

  Hasher hasher = Hashing.hmacSha1(key).newHasher();
  Hasher hasher2 = Hashing.hmacSha1(key).newHasher();

  hasher.putBytes(valueToDigest.getBytes());
  hasher2.putBytes(valueToDigest.getBytes());

  // This is what I used and also found a few online hash generators using the same approach
  String hashAsString = hasher.hash().toString();

  // This is what the external system used
  byte[] hashAsByte = hasher2.hash().asBytes();

  String base64AsString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashAsString.getBytes());
  String base64AsByte = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashAsByte);

  System.out.println("Hash As String: " + hashAsString);
  System.out.println("Hash As String(Converted to Bytes): " + hashAsString.getBytes());  
  System.out.println("Base64 Value of Hash As String: " + base64AsString);
  System.out.println("Hash As Byte: " + hashAsByte);
  System.out.println("Base64 Value of Hash As Byte: " + base64AsByte);

  /*** My Results ***/
  // Hash As String: c8094bb1e0896a3f813036bdaeb37b753d9f4f5b
  // Hash As String(Converted to Bytes): [B@61443d8f
  // Base64 Value of Hash As String: YzgwOTRiYjFlMDg5NmEzZjgxMzAzNmJkYWViMzdiNzUzZDlmNGY1Yg==
  
  /*** External System Results ***/
  // Hash As Byte: [B@445b84c0
  // Base64 Value of Hash As Byte: yAlLseCJaj+BMDa9rrN7dT2fT1s=

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 encodes bytes, the hasher produce bytes, so there's no reason to convert to String.

I suppose examples you have seen are about converting base64 starting from strings variables.

Different result are due to different encoding of toString() or getBytes() conversions.

From guava documentation you can see hashcode.toString() converts in exadecimal, while bytes.toString() is platform dependent (supposedly UTF8)?

https://guava.dev/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/HashCode.html#toString()
https://guava.dev/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/HashCode.html#fromString(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Hmm, so I guess the online hash generators should only be used to check that the hash itself is correct, not as a starting point for Base64-encoding. toString(), iirc, uses UTF-16. Trying to encode that value to Base64 is probably not the intended use for these online hash checkers. For Base64, I gather I should always first convert the hash to bytes and then Base64-encode. My misunderstanding probably came from how to leverage these online hash checkers and I incorrectly used that as a jumping off point to Base64-encode the hash. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user3621633: You seem to have a fundamental confusion about bytes, characters, and strings in Java. `toString()` doesn't "use" utf-16, it produces a string. UTF-16 is a method for encoding/decoding Strings to byte array and vice versa. Guava's hashing classes can give you a result as a byte array or a hexadecimal string. The hex string is mostly useful for human observation. What's the *right* format? That depends on what you want to do with the result.

Comment: Sorry: I meant Strings are internally represented as UTF-16 in Java, iirc. Thank you for further clarification, as well, on encoding.